# Django: mail to gmail errors intermittently?

Tags: django, email, gmail

I've been getting these errors intermittently from sending email from my django app. I send very few emails, so the number of these errors is alarming.

Sending email works intermittently as well when doing it by hand :

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'spam@paulisageek.com', ['spam@paulisageek.com'], fail_silently=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/home/ptarjan/django-dev/mysite/django/core/mail.py", line 390, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/var/home/ptarjan/django-dev/mysite/django/core/mail.py", line 266, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/var/home/ptarjan/django-dev/mysite/django/core/mail.py", line 172, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/var/home/ptarjan/django-dev/mysite/django/core/mail.py", line 186, in _send
    email_message.message().as_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 704, in sendmail
    (code,resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 494, in data
    (code,msg)=self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 352, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 160, in readline
    chr = self.sslobj.read(1)
sslerror: The read operation timed out
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'spam@paulisageek.com', ['spam@paulisageek.com'], fail_silently=False)
1
```

Am I misconfiguring something? Is gmail blocking me? Is gmail having problems and this is a side-effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail was having intermittent problems today: [cnn article](http://www.cnn.com/2009/TECH/09/01/gmail.outage/).